# How to know if I have authorized access to remote pcs

Tags: vb.net, wmi

I'm using the code below to retrieve some information from remote pcs. Although I have authorized access to most of the pcs but not all.

I have a list of pc names, and my winforms will read it from there.
So my question is, how do I know if I have authorized access to certain pcs?

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
    objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & line & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

    strISC = "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer"
    On Error Resume Next
    objReg.GetStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strISC, "svcKBNumber", strKB)
    On Error Resume Next
    objReg.GetStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strISC, "svcVersion", strsvcVersion)
    On Error Resume Next
```

by the way, I know this is actually in vbscript but I was able to use it in vb.net also.

Comment: Take out the `On Error Resume Next` and replace it with structured error handling. Then if an exception is thrown it is likely you don't have access to that machine.

Comment: @MattWilko Thanks! :)